# upgrade option in odoo 11 module does not appear

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11, erp

After I install Odoo 11 and configure it successfully I make custom addons dir named *custom_addons* contain addon named HMS, till now no thing went wrong as I find the module after I change Odoo setting and run as a developer but after I edit the model file and add fields and save I did not find upgrade option witch allow to map model as table in database.

Can anyone help?

This is screenshot to module where there is no option to upgrade:

[image: screenshot to module]

edit(1): screenshot to logs
[image: logs screenshot]

Comment: Hi,  can you please check the message error in the log file

Comment: Hi Karara, actually I run using Ubuntu so the logs is run live on server and I edit my question adding screenshot to it logs

Comment: @ Karara Mohamed after I review the logs I found that module does not installed but I don't know why the log message is (WARNING odoo11DB odoo.modules.module: module hms: module not found)

Comment: Hey @hossam, we'd appreciate it if you could copy the logs into a code block (not an image) in your original question. You can edit the original question and add the code block with the new error (below your original question). If some error messages are repeating over and over, you don't have to post more than one instance of the same error.

Comment: Hi @hossam aboouf check in your config file if existing the path to your module HMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are still in install / update mode. This can happen if an update fails.

When you change your models especially when add new fields you need to restart the server before you trigger the update so the new python code is loaded into the odoo process.

You can try to fix that by running the following command while your server is stopped:
`odoo -u base --stop-after-init`
This upgrades all modules depending on module base (which is all modules).

After the update is successful you can start your server back up normally.